# converges to infinity in complex plain

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $(z_1,z_2,z_3,\ldots)$ be a sequence of complex numbers. Is it reasonable to define $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n=\infty$ whenever $\lim_{n\to\infty}|z_n|=\infty$?

Under this definition some results which are true in $\mathbb R$ are no longer true in $\mathbb C$. For instance, it is no longer true that $\infty+\infty=\infty$ since $z_n=(-2)^n+2^n$ have no limit, while $2^n$ and $(-2)^n$ converges to $\infty$.

Comment: It's not only reasonable, it's the only way that agrees with the topology of the Riemann sphere. But note that $\infty+\infty=\infty$ never held in the reals. It held in the two-point compactification of the real line, $\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$, which is homeomorphic to a closed interval. But not in the one-point compactification $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$, which is homeomorphic to a circle. So it makes sense that it also doesn't hold in the one-point compactification $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ of the complex plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it absolutely makes sense. It is called the Alexandroff extension or one-point compactification of the space. In case of the complex plane you obtain the Riemann sphere, which is well-known and an important tool in complex analysis. There are also other compactifications like the radial compactification and the Stone-Čech compactification, where you add more than just one point at infinity. But you are right that either way you can't reasonably extend your usual operations to the extension.

Comment: Thanks Klaus for your answer!

Comment: Well, you have $\infty\cdot \infty=\infty$, $\frac1\infty=0$ and $\frac10=\infty$ (but not $\infty\cdot0=1$).